# Problema na array do Foreach

Tags: php, html

Meu problema é o seguinte, espero que possam me ajudar:

Estou buscando alguns registros da tabela "Produtos" do meu banco de dados e exibindo ela no front. Estou usando um Foreach para trazer esses registros e há também um botão que irá criar uma sessão e adicionar esses produtos ao meu carrinho. O problema não é no carrinho em si e sim na lista onde está localizado o botão que irá adicionar. Ele chama um Action referenciando se há uma ação (o action, né) e o id do produto. O caminho fica mais ou menos assim:

---> localhost/LoginandRegisterLanchenet/carrinho.php?add=carrinho&id=

O id fica vazio e não referencia a nada resultando em um erro de URL não encontrada. Segue abaixo o código que abaixo:

```
<?php
$conect = new db();
$conect = $conect ->conectar();



$query = mysqli_query($conect, "SELECT * FROM produto");
$result = mysqli_fetch_all($query);


echo "<div  class='quadcard1'>CRIAR RESERVA<br><br>";
echo "<div class='quadcard2' > Cardápio<br><br>";
foreach ($result as $item){
    echo "<div class='quadcard'>";
    echo "<div class='produtos'>".$item[1]."<a href='carrinho.php?add=carrinho&id='".$item[0]."'><input class='btn btn-primary' type='button' value='+' style='display: relative; float : right; margin-right :1rem; margin-top: 0.5rem;'></a><br>".$item[3]." <label class='valor'> Valor: R$ ".$item [5]."</label></div></div>";
}

echo "<div></div>";
echo "</div></div>";
?>
```

Alguém conseguiu identificar o erro?

Caso precise de mais detalhes é só dizer que eu acrescento.

Grato!! 
Att.

Comment: Antes do foreach eu recomendo você verificar o que tem dentro do seu result.
Tente adicionar isso antes do foreach: print_r($result)

Comment: Não deveria dar erro de URL não encontrada por causa do id, já que ele é apenas um parâmetro da URL. A página em si é `carrinho.php`.

Comment: Acho que `$item[0]` não é o valor que estás a espera. Como sugerido acima, um `print_r($result)` antes do foreach, e mesmo `print_r($item)` dentro do ciclo pode-te ajudar a perceber como está estruturado o array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simulei como poderia estar o array e abaixo tem um código explicativo. Execute o var_dump para ver a saída. Parece ser o que você procura.
É necessário validar que o ID não seja vazio para não dar erro em sua URL. Você tem que validar para que não seja passado um produto sem id.

```
<?php

$result[] = [
    0 => 7, //id
    1 => 'mouse', //produto
    2 => 14, // quantidade
    3 => 12.00 //valor Unitario
];

$result[] = [
    0 => NULL, //id
    1 => 'pendrive', //produto
    2 => 140, // quantidade
    3 => 35.00 //valor Unitario
];

$result[] = [
    0 => '', //id
    1 => '', //produto
    2 => '', // quantidade
    3 => '' //valor Unitario
];

$result[] = [
    0 => NULL, //id
    1 => NULL, //produto
    2 => NULL, // quantidade
    3 => NULL //valor Unitario
];

//var_dump($result); 

foreach ($result as $item) {
    $id = $item[0];
    $produto = $item[1];

    if ($id != '' || !empty($id)) {
        echo "\n Existe " . "ID: " . $id;
        //continue; // Ou seja pula estes nulos
    } else {
        echo "\n Nulos ou vazios (Sem id)";
    }
}
```

Simulando o array de result acima para listar em view segundo seu código listado seria:
(apenas troquei umas variáveis e fiz a validação de vazio primeiro para depois listar os dados)

```
<?php
// Abre conexão
$conect = new db();
$conect = $conect ->conectar();

// Executa a query
$query = mysqli_query($conect, "SELECT * FROM produto");
// Retorna um array com os dados
$result = mysqli_fetch_all($query);

echo "<div  class='quadcard1'>iFood<br><br>";
echo "<div class='quadcard2' > Cardápio<br><br>";

// Percorre os dados
foreach ($result as $item) {
    $id = $item[0];
    $produto = $item[1];
    $qtdeEstoque = $item[2];
    $valor = $item[3];

    if ($id == '' || empty($id)) {
        // Se tiver um id vazio ele pula
        continue;
    } else {
        // Se tiver id ele mostra o produto
        echo "<div class='quadcard'>";
        echo "<div class='produtos'>" . $produto . "<a href='carrinho.php?add=carrinho&id='" . $id . "'><input class='btn btn-primary' type='button' value='+' style='display: relative; float : right; margin-right :1rem; margin-top: 0.5rem;'></a><br>" . $qtdeEstoque . " <label class='valor'> Valor: R$ " . $valor . "</label></div></div>";        
    }
}

echo "<div></div>";
echo "</div></div>";
```